# Change ReadOnlyView property for Subject view in SP2013 Team discussion list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, powershell, team-sites

I am trying to update the `ReadOnlyView property` of the Subject view of a SP2013 Team discussion list.

When I set `$viewname.ReadOnlyView = $true`, PowerShell throws an error saying that `this is a read-only field`.

I have seen some blogs that propose updating through SP Designer, but that is not an option on my farm since it is not allowed.

Are there any other ways to customize the Subject view via PowerShell or C# code?